# Which values do f:ajax render accept

Tags: ajax, jsf, render

In JSF I can update components with ajax:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I found some of these values in the web: `@form @this @parent @none @region @all`.

Is there a complete list of the standard values which come with `<f:ajax>`? And do these values have a special name which I could lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look in [`<f:ajax>` tag documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html).

> #### render
>
> Evaluates to `Collection<String>`. The clientIds of components that will participate in the "render" portion of the Request Processing Lifecycle. If a literal is specified the identifiers must be space delimited. Any of the keywords "`@this`", "`@form`", "`@all`", "`@none`" may be specified in the identifier list. If not specified, the default value of "`@none`" is assumed. For example, `@this clientIdOne clientIdTwo`.

The others you mentioned (`@region` and `@parent`) are recognizable as from PrimeFaces `<p:ajax>`. So if you were actually facing problems while trying that on `<f:ajax>`, you should now understand why.